# pagedown editor full screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, pagedown

I'm using [pagedown editor](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html). Its a clone of stackoverflow editor.

[This is the official project page](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) of that editor.

Can someone tell me how to implement fullscreen mode.?

In fullscreen mode I want the `editor in the left 50% area` and `preview in the right 50% area`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of taking time to trick the system , please take time to show us what you did ..

my solution as im like most of the others wont go around and download the plugin and try , will be doing so ..

```
    $(function(){
$('.link-to-fullscreen').click(function(){
    $('.wmd-panel').css({'width':'100%'});
})
    })
```

put it under the code for the plugin !
and play around with the values and you should get the result that you want ..

Comment: I think you still don't understand my question. I'm not asking how to make the editor width 100%. I'm asking here, how to implement the full screen mode. Which mean I have a link called "Full screen mode". When the user click that link the editor should expand to full screen. Thanks for your input though

Comment: bind a click event to element and then in the callback function do the width increasing and stuff...